# Оптимизация работы с Bitmap на Android

Tags: android, bitmap

Добрый день!

Пишу приложение которое использует кучу разных изображений, мини игра. Все оформление идет в виде PNG. Проблема в том что по дизайну надо собирать задний фон из нескольких PNG и растягивать на всю ширину экрана. Так же используются разного рода дополнительные картинки каждая которая занимает по 25% от экрана.

Читал мануал официальный по оптимизации, он сильно не помогает так как экран как правило больше ширины всех картинок и оптимизации там особой нет.
В памяти все эти картинки разрастаются до 100 мегабайт. Хотя в реале они весят шне больше 1.5 мегабайт. Я подчищаю и удаляю картинки где только это возможно.

Есть ли способы уменьшить объем занимаемой памяти?
Если к примеру я гружу одну картинку Bitmap по ширине экрана примерно 724 на 1280 это занимает в памяти уже 12-15 мегабайт. 
Это совершенно не приемлемо. Как то же пишут игры где кучу разной анимации и графических элементов.

Comment: 724*1280*4 = 3 мегабайта. Config.ARGB565, уменьшать картинки и выводить в ImageView fit'ом, decode in sample size, и т.п. Недавно видос был  https://youtu.be/HY9aaXHx8yA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет шансов написать подобное приложение на canvas нормально. Возьмите какую-то библиотеку/движок (libgdx, adengine) которые умеют работать с openGL и упаковывайте все свои картинки в атлас, загружайте как текстуру в память видеоадаптера и будите выводить как вам угодно не тратя памяти приложения.

Можно конечно просто на openGL все это делать,не подключая сторонние движки, это не так сложно, но придется довольно много вникать, посмотрите тут, есть статьи + исходники для спрайтовой анимации (ищите файл ogl3, ogl4 в теме).

http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=418429

Но все же проще посмотреть на libgdx, ну слишком долго и сложно вникать в openGL пару месяцев то запросто улетят, даже на простейшие вещи.